# Adding FieldOffset to PropertyChangedEventHandler

Tags: c#

```
namespace Program
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public class Block : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] private byte[] _byteData;
        public Block()
        {
            _byteData = new byte[10];
        }

        public byte[] ByteData { get => _byteData; set => _byteData = value; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

When I build the code I get below error

**Error: error CS0625: 'Block.PropertyChanged': instance field in types marked with StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit) must have a FieldOffset attribute**

When I tried to resolve this error by adding FieldOffset attribute to the PropertyChanged event something like below,

`[FieldOffset(1)] public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`

I am getting below error message

**Error: error CS0592: Attribute 'FieldOffset' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field' declarations.**

How can I resolve this issue?
Is it possible to have INotifyPropertyChanged inteface implemented when we use StructLayout?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-custom-event-accessors

Comment: How does custom event help?

Comment: It lets you apply [FieldOffset] to the PropertyChangedEventHandler backing field, just like you did for the ByteData property.  Having an event in an interop declaration is a major code-smell btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
[field: FieldOffset(8)]
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Specify the target as field. But you cannot use `FieldOffset(1)` as it will cause `PropertyChanged` and `_byteData` overlap. If you want to define a union, you need to use `IntPtr` instead.

Comment: What is the difference between [field: FieldOffset(8)] and [FieldOffset(8)]? I should be using offset value as 10 right if my byte array is of size 10?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/#attribute-targets

Comment: You can't, in 64-bit programs, the offset of managed types must be a multiple of 8.

Comment: I don't think so, in below microsoft page I see offset 14 which is not a multiple of 8. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/how-to-create-a-c-cpp-union-by-using-attributes